# Connection to AWS ActiveMQ broker using Python

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, activemq-classic

I am able to establish connection to AWS ActiveMQ OpenWire broker with ssl from JMS (Java Messaging Service). But not able to do connection to AWS ActiveMQ broker with SSL from Python. Any link and document, will be helpful.

Comment: What wire protocol and client runtime library are you using for Python? How far have you got so far, and what happens? The tricky part here is usually getting the broker's server certificate -- which is probably in JKS format -- to a place and format the Python client will understand.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is understanding the key/cert files must be there - otherwise even stomp.py tests in their repository will not work. TLS will not work in stomp.py if the file names are not specified (correctly).

See the code & key generation instructions here: https://gist.github.com/borislitvak/6ccea503abf1b2f9c89e87309d6dab88